# broadcast receiver for softkeyboard change android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-softkeyboard

Is there any broadcast which gets fire when softkeyboard change in android. I just want to track the keyboard change event. Is it possible in android?

Comment: please give me reason for down vote.

Comment: Did you got any solution? Is it possible to detect if the keyboard has changed in settings?

Answer (score 1):

Try to override `registerReceiver` and `unregisterReceiver` in `InputMethodService`. They are called every time user changes default keyboard in settings.